# DVC reproduction failure

Tags: dvc

When I am using this dvc.yaml code:

```
stages:
  get_data:
    cmd: python get_data.py
    deps:
    - get_data.py
    outs:
    - data_raw.csv
```

and running "dvc repro" command I am getting ERROR: failed to reproduce

I tried with some changes such as running some other configuration but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you share more details? Run with `-v` flag and share the output, try to run `python get_data.py` outside DVC and see if that works,.